# String index out of bounds

Tags: java, string, char

This is my code to add to binary strings, I am getting correct value in `res` string but it still gives me an exception at the end of execution.
The strings `m1` & `m2` are of equal length of 28 each.
Still I tried running the loop just 10 times to verify but error still persists.
This holds true for any value of `i`, irrespective of greater than or lesser than actual length of both strings.

```
public static String addMantissa(String m1,String m2)
{
    String res=" ";
    int c=0;
    System.out.println("Length is " + m2.length());
    int i=0;
    while(i < m2.length())
    {
        System.out.print(" " + res.charAt(i));
        if(m1.charAt(i)=='1' && m2.charAt(i)=='1')
        {
            if(c==0)
            {
                res+="0";
                c=1;
            }
            else
            {
                res+="1";
                c=1;
            }
        }

        if(m1.charAt(i)=='1' && m2.charAt(i)=='0')
        {
            if(c==0)
            {
                res+="1";
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                res+="0";
                c=1;
            }
        }

        if(m1.charAt(i)=='0' && m2.charAt(i)=='1')
        {
            if(c==0)
            {
                res+="1";
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                res+="0";
                c=1;
            }
        }

        if(m1.charAt(i)=='0' && m2.charAt(i)=='0')
        {
            if(c==0)
            {
                res+="0";
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                res+="1";
                c=0;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your actual error and trace.

Comment: what is the input (m1 & m2)??

Comment: Those middle 2 if-statements can be replaced with 1 if you separate the conditions by OR (`||`), or, a little more hacky - `m1.charAt(i) + m2.charAt(i) == '1' + '0'`, or `m1.charAt(i)-'0' + m2.charAt(i)-'0' == 1`. And I would replace those `charAt`'s with temp variables (with `'0'` subtracted).

Comment: Your code works fine for me even with strings of length greater than 28. The problem might be with the place where you take m1 and m2 as inputs.m1 & m2 might be of different length or there is a possiblity of a space in any one of this inputs when you enter them. can you post that code?

Comment: I'll put money on there being something faulty on the input (like a `\n` that wasn't stripped) and then `res` not being appended to and throwing an `index` exception

Comment: this is my exception
  
Length is 28
   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 28
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
 at SinglePrecision.main(SinglePrecision.java:57)

Comment: Are there always spaces in your input?

Comment: @TheMerovingian spaces are appended by me, input never has spaces

Comment: Could you please check my latest answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your entire method can be replaced by just one line:

```
public static String addMantissa(String m1, String m2) {
    return new BigInteger(m1, 2).add(new BigInteger(m2, 2)).toString(2);
}
```

The size of 28 bits mentioned in your question means that the `Integer` class could have neen used for parsing, but using `BigInteger` means that strings of *any* size can be handled.

You should use the JDK instead of reinventing the wheel.

Also, "less code is good" is a great mantra (provided the code remains clear, of course), and this code has high density.

Comment: where shal i put the end bracket its giving me an error for dat

Comment: Sorry - I left out a closing bracket. Fixed now - see edited answer. (I typed this code in on my iPhone... sometimes my in-brain compiler misses things like that)

Comment: it gave me this exception tho

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 26
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
 at SinglePrecision.main(Unknown Source)

Comment: What values are you passing to the method? And are you using the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

@ShreyosAdikari is basically right.

```
System.out.print(" " + res.charAt(i));
```

Should be called at the end of the loop, as then res[i] is filled.
Maybe you meant:

```
System.out.print((" " + res).charAt(i));
```

But then you do not print the last loop's res.

Comment: i commented that line too, i dont think there is an error there.

Comment: I give another answer sir.Can you please validate the same?

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari, as you changed your answer, I remove my reference to you prior answer. Your new answer is of course rock-solid, defensively programmed, like I would have done too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception comes from the line

```
 while(i < m2.length())
```

You need to change it to

```
while(i < m2.length() && i<m1.length())
```

As if m1(say 1) has a length lower than m2(say 4) and you checking only the value of m2. Then in the second iteration it will enter the loop as 2<4, and when it tryes to get m1.carAt(2) (as the length 1) it will throw String index out of bounds exception.

Comment: yes u r right, the excpetion is on dat line, but adding && condition dint work me, coz strings are as it is of same length.

Comment: Then you have to change the whole logic accordingly.